# Prevent duplication of empty row inserted in my data base each time after my .php page refresh

Tags: php

I have .php page where I am inserting various inputs. It directs those inputs to my data base page in phpmyadmin but it also creates empty cells in my data base(phpmyadmin) which I do not want. Can you help me to prevent this empty duplication.

Comment: your database is Mysql. Phpmyadmin is a tool to display and interact with the database.

Comment: @LelioFaieta that is right data base phpmysql. How to remove duplication of empty rows. I am new to development. if you can help

Comment: "data base phpmysql" ...no, the database is just **mysql**. PHP is a programming language

Comment: The link shown in the yellow box above your question gives suggestions about how to solve your problem - it has been discussed many times before already.